# Android app download torrent to NAS?

Tags: android, nas, bittorrent, mobile-phone

I have a Western Digital NAS (MyBook Live). I want to add torrents to the NAS with my android phone.

My idea of a workflow:

- Add android app for adding torrents to a list.
- Somehow connect the phone to the NAS.

( I also use Boxee Box as a Media Center )

Answer (score 0):

Haha, since there are *some* legitimate torrents out there, I'll give you an overview:

You'll probably need a rooted phone. I would pull up a shell on my phone, mount my NAS share to something like /Downloads/torrents or whatever, and use the torrent apps like uTorrent to download them to that folder. Obviously you'll need access to your NAS *all* the time, so if you plan on using this away from home then you'll want to implement something like OpenVPN on the NAS' network, then use the OpenVPN client on your phone to stay wired in.